# Is the span of a universal kernel on a compact metric space dense in the space of continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space, and $k:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, universal kernel on $X$. By definition of a universal kernel, the RKHS corresponding to $k$, defined as

$$ \mathcal{H} = \overline{\mathrm{span}}\{k(x,\cdot):x\in X\}, $$

*i.e.*, the closure of the span of the evaluation functionals with respect to the Hilbert norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{H}}$, is dense in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ (the space of continuous functions on $X$) with respect to the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

What I would like to know is how the span of the evaluation functionals relates to $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.
In particular, define the pre-Hilbert space

$$ \mathcal{H}_0 = \mathrm{span}\{k(x,\cdot):x\in X\}, $$

so that $\mathcal{H}=\overline{\mathcal{H}_0}$, where the closure is again taken with respect to the norm of the Hilbert space inner product.
The question that remains for me: is $\mathcal{H}_0$ dense in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ *with respect to the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$*?

I don't think that the Hilbert space norm is equivalent to the sup-norm, so I can't claim that the Cauchy sequences in $\mathcal{H}_0$ with respect to the Hilbert norm are also Cauchy with respect to the sup-norm, unless I am missing some property of universal kernels.

Comment: If the kernel is bounded then Cauchy sequences in $H$ with respect to the sup norm will be Cauchy with respect to the norm on $H$, but I’m not sure about the converse.

Comment: Good direction: thinking about that a little bit, an extra condition can help us get there. If there is some uniform lower bound $L>0$ for $k(x,x)$ for all $x\in X$, then any Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}_0$ with respect to the norm on $\mathcal{H}_0$ will also be a Cauchy sequence with respect to the sup norm.

Comment: @user27182 Can you clarify that? Why is it that Cauchy convergence in the sup norm implies Cauchy convergence with respect to the norm on $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Apologies, I got it the wrong way around, what I meant was that (by Cauchy-Schwartz) $||f(x) - g(x)||_\infty = \sup_{x} |\langle f - g, k_x\rangle| \le ||f - g||_{\mathcal{H}} \sup_x \sqrt{k(x, x)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the kernel $k$ is assumed to be continuous and $X$ is assumed compact, there exists an $L>0$ such that for all $x\in X$, it holds that $k(x,x)>L$. Now, suppose that $(f_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H_0}$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{H}}$.
Thus, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{L}} &\geq \|f_m-f_n\|_{\mathcal{H}} \\
&= \sup_{g\in\mathcal{H}_0:\|g\|_{\mathcal{H}}\leq 1}\langle f_m-f_n, g\rangle \\
&\geq \sup_{x\in X}\big|\langle f_m-f_n, \frac{k(x,\cdot)}{\|k(x,\cdot)\|_{\mathcal{H}}}\rangle\big| \\
&= \sup_{x\in X}\big|\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(x,x)}}\big|\cdot\big|f_m(x)-f_n(x)\big| \\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\|f_m-f_n\|_\infty.
\end{align*}

Therefore, $(f_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is also Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

To complete the proof, let $g\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be given.
Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $f\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $\|g-f\|_\infty\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Since $\mathcal{H}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{H}_0$, there exists a Cauchy sequence $(f_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ in $\mathcal{H}_0$ that converges to $f$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{H}}$.
By the argument above, it must also converge to $f$ in the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.
Thus, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, it holds that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
By the triangle inequality, this implies that for all $n\geq N$, $\|f_n-g\|_\infty\leq\epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: Why exactly can’t the kernel vanish somewhere?

Comment: By the reproducing kernel property of a kernel, $k(x,x)=\langle k(x,\cdot), k(x,\cdot)\rangle$. Since the function $k(x,\cdot)$ is the evaluation functional at $x$, it is a nonzero element of the Hilbert space, so that the above inner product is nonzero.

Comment: Why can’t we have $k(x, \cdot)=0$ for some $x$, am I missing something? This would of course mean that all functions in the RKHS vanish at that $x$, but is this really a problem?

Comment: A universal kernel on a compact space is one whose RKHS is dense in the space of continuous functions with respect to the sup-norm. So, for instance, one can approximate a function taking constant value 1 uniformly well, and such an approximation certainly wouldn't vanish at any point.

Comment: Of course, thanks.